# trying to use variables in a swift UIColor

Tags: swift, uicolor

Trying to create the colors of the rectangle using variables

```
import UIKit

class Color: UIView
{
    var colors = ViewController()

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect)
    {

        let swiftColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 165/255, blue: 0, alpha: 1);

        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5.0)
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context,
            UIColor(red: CGFloat(colors.red1), green: CGFloat(colors.green1), blue: CGFloat(colors.blue1), alpha: 1.0))
        let rectangle = CGRectMake(60,170,200,80)
        CGContextAddRect(context, rectangle)
        CGContextStrokePath(context)
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context,
            UIColor(red: CGFloat(colors.red1), green: CGFloat(colors.green1), blue: CGFloat(colors.blue1), alpha: 1.0))
            CGContextFillRect(context, rectangle)
    }
}
```

getting an error that says there is an extra argument 'green' in call

the variables are floats from a different class and should work fine

Comment: We need to see your definition of `ViewController`, as I suspect the error is in one of your properties `.red1`, `.green1`, `.blue1` (likely .green1).  Your initial `let swiftColor = ` line compiles ok, but I doubt it does what you think it will, as  165/255 will translate to 0 as you are dividing `Ints`. Be very careful to cast things that you want as `CGFloats` to actual CGFloats!

Answer (score 0):

`CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor` takes `CGColor` arguments, not `UIColor`. From the docs:

`func CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(c: CGContext!, color: CGColor!)`

Answer (score 0):

```
                                                                                                         v  // Just delete this extra parenthesis and you will be fine 
UIColor(red: CGFloat(colors.red1), green: CGFloat(colors.green1), blue: CGFloat(colors.blue1), alpha: 1.0))
```

It should be like this:

```
UIColor(red: CGFloat(colors.red1), green: CGFloat(colors.green1), blue: CGFloat(colors.blue1), alpha: 1.0)
```